# Teradata database Size

Tags: database, optimization, teradata

I am working in Teradata database my database utilization is above 90%. I cannot delete the data from the tables so I applied COMPRESS logic to the columns which has repeated values. By doing this my Database size got reduced to some extent.please help me if there is any other way to reduce database size/utilization ?

Comment: Are you using appropriately sized data types? What is your data distribution for the tables in the database? How are you applying compression in the table? Did you compress enough values? Did you compress too many? Do you have unnecessary secondary indexes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Compression in Teradata](http://www.teradata-sql.com/2012/04/compression-in-teradata.html).
As a side note: 90% utilization doesn't necessarily mean, that after it reaches 100% it will break. It'll probably just expand, but to be certain you need to check proper options of your db.

Comment: Databases in Teradata do not auto-expand like other RDBMS platforms such as SQL Server.